# Как реализовать "архивный тип товара" на 1С-Битрикс?

Tags: php, mysql, битрикс

Имеется 1С-Битрикс (v16.0.9), редакция "Бизнес". На нашем сайте (интернет-магазин) несколько тысяч товаров. И есть задача некоторые товары убрать с продаж. Но необходимо сохранить его в поисковой выдаче, т.е. оставить детальную страницу. Ну и, неплохо было бы подписать что товар "В архиве".

В битриксе есть способ деактивации товара, но это не подходит.

Прошу подсказать мне, как это делается в Битрикс правильно?

Заранее благодарю за ответ!

Comment: Я с Вами согласен, сам не сторонник Битрикса. Но увы, что имеем, с тем и приходится разбираться. 

У нас стоит не такая уж и сложная задача. Но я даже не могу представить как это сделать внашем случае. 

Другое дело, если бы наш интермаг был написан на каком-нибудь из фреймворков, то решение бы свелось к замене условия в SQL-запросе и редактировании пары-тройки файлов.

Answer (score 2):

Можно добавить к товару (или к разделу) свойство а-ля "Не продавать", в шаблоне проверять его наличие и при наличии убирать кнопку "купить" или делать ее неактивной.

Answer (score 0):

Поставить товару количественный учет и отменить продажу в минус. У количество товара поставить 0. Тогда оно не попадет в корзину. И если это стандартный шаблон битрикс на товар или будет подписка или будет писать что он не в наличии